# Bug in sidebar of “Ask Question” page

Tags: bug, status-declined

I noticed a bug. When you scroll down on the Ask Question page, the sidebar on the right pushes into the footer. Seen on both Chrome and Safari.

Safari Version 8.0.6 (10600.6.3)

Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.3

Chrome Version 43.0.2357.81 (64-bit)

[image: SAFARI Sidebar pushing into the footer]

[image: CHROME Sidebar pushing into the footer]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/right-hand-sidebar-covers-the-footer-on-the-ask-question-page-and-markdown-hel