# Left menu on Teams page overlaps the footer

Tags: bug, design

I just viewed the [Stack Overflow Team page](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team) and noticed a user interface issue.
When I scroll the page to the bottom, the left menu overlaps the info in the page footer:

[image: cosmetics bug]

Comment: I see the same on Win10, Chrome 49.0.2623.75

Comment: Quick fix: `#footer{position:relative}`. Problem solved.

Comment: While not the same page, this is scarily similar to [this design bug which was 'status-declined'](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295985/bug-in-sidebar-of-ask-question-page)

Comment: @AndrewT. but the status-declined one was not that bad. This one looks bad BAD. pleeease fix it. ++Jacob.

Comment: @MiquelColl I forgot to update my comment here: based on MSE's experience, it seems SE will only add background color to the menu, the positioning will be still like that (possible to overlap footer). I could be wrong though

Comment: @AndrewT. if there is a background color in the div it will not be as bad as I said. sooo.. yeah

Comment: Not a single employee of SO is from India. :'(

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy maybe it's because they are based in new york, and all employees, onsite and remote, have to be available to collaborate in the afternoon.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I know of at least one Stack Overflow employee who is from India. They currently do not reside in India, but they are from India.

Comment: @Hynes just curious, any plans to fix this bug? Or is it not as trivial as it seems to fix? :(

Comment: Just use `position: sticky` instead of using JS to toggle between `position: static` and `position: fixed`.