# The sidemenu hangs over the footer on the team page

Tags: bug

On the [team page](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team) the left sidebar hangs over the footer once you scroll down to the bottom. The page would need to be at least 997px high to accommodate both the footer and sidebar which means this happens any screens with a height of less than 1200px since the browser's top bar and the dock/taskbar on your OS will take up 100px - 200px.

[image: team page]

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318357/left-menu-on-teams-page-overlaps-the-footer