# Who are all of the default unikong high scorers?

Tags: discussion, unikong

So in true arcade fashion, I'm assuming  that all of the default values on the high scores are linked to either developers or other mentionable people. I can work out a couple people but who are the rest?

[image]

JON - Jon Skeet

DHA - [David Haney](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2420979/haney)

Comment: Those numbers are fake (except your own). [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhGXa.png) is how it looks for me normally, and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoRK6.png) is how it looks in incognito mode. My score doesn't show up in incognito mode, and it's not the same users who have the other scores (except that Jon Skeet always has the most).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your screenshot...

```
Alex Warren
Alec Gorge
Shane Madden
Adam Maras
David Haney
Jarrod Dixon
Kirti Thorat
Jon Chan
George Beech
```

You can work out the rest with [this handy guide](http://web.archive.org/web/20160401160752/https://stackoverflow.com/company/team).

Comment: FYI that page seems a little broken.  If you scroll all the way to the bottom the left hand menu floats over the page footer.  Would you like a bug report?

Comment: @NathanOliver Sounds like the same issue we have with the sidebar when scrolling all the way to the bottom. (It's reported somewhere.) Can't hurt to report it, but I doubt we'll fix it on it any time soon.

Comment: No problem.  Just figured I would point it out since I noticed it.  it's not harming the unicorns so it can wait ;)

Comment: Thanks! I had hoped (imagined) it was the top 10 high scorers from some office hijinks rather than the more likely string manipulations. Still cool :D

Comment: @NathanOliver Apparently it's already reported - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318357/left-menu-on-teams-page-overlaps-the-footer