# Right Menu in Editing help page overlaps the footer

Tags: bug, user-interface, editing-help

The right menu in [Editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page overlaps the footer content when scrolled to the bottom.

[image: Right menu overlapping Footer]

**Browser:** Google Chrome

Comment: Related, pretty much the same problem: ["How to Format" sidebar overlaps footer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266747)

Comment: And another one: [Bug in sidebar of “Ask Question” page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295985/bug-in-sidebar-of-ask-question-page)